# location via WiFi, cell tower not working anymore

Tags: location-services, 9.0-pie

I have a Nokia 8 Sirocco with Android 9 (kernel version 4.4.153-perf+ #1). Since a few weeks ago I noticed that the phone seems to be unable to get its non-GPS based location - e.g. via WiFi locations or cell tower triangulation.

The symptoms are:

- Google Location history is less accurate.
- My shared location only updates for the other persons whenever an app uses GPs (and there is a GPS signal).
- I keep seeing an "Updating your shared location" notification.
- Apps that rely on location services take longer to boot up or be responsive.
- Apps that rely on location services do not work at all without an available GPS signal.
- Location based Smart unlock is not working.
- Location based reminders are not working.

I have checked the following settings under *Security & Location* » *Privacy* » *Location*:

- Under *Google Location Accuracy* the *Improve Location Accuracy* is **On**.
- Under *App-level permissions* all relevant apps have permission to access the device's location.
- Under *Scanning* both *Wi-Fi scanning* and *Bluetooth scanning* are **On**.

Is there anything more I could do to get this working properly again?

Comment: Wild shot- try disabling location accuracy, reboot, enable and check

Comment: @beeshyams while this seems to have worked initially for a while - the behaviour is now back again unfortunately. This makes me conclude that either **a)** there is a bug within Android 9 or **b)** there is a bug that occurs with Android 9 only on the Nokia 8 Sirocco or **c)** something is wrong with the phone itself.